# AWS Boto3 "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I am trying to get the list of CF Stacks with preferred items "Stack Name", "StackStatus" and "DriftInformation".

I tried the following and it throws an error

"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')

response = client.list_stacks(
    )

list = response['StackSummaries']['StackName']

print(list)
```

Here is the response syntax.

```
   'StackSummaries': [
        {
            'StackId': 'string',
            'StackName': 'string',
            'TemplateDescription': 'string',
            'CreationTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'LastUpdatedTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'DeletionTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'StackStatus': 'CREATE_IN_PROGRESS'|'CREATE_FAILED'|'CREATE_COMPLETE'|'ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS'|'ROLLBACK_FAILED'|'ROLLBACK_COMPLETE'|'DELETE_IN_PROGRESS'|'DELETE_FAILED'|'DELETE_COMPLETE'|'UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_COMPLETE'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE'|'REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS',
            'StackStatusReason': 'string',
            'ParentId': 'string',
            'RootId': 'string'
        },
    ],
    'NextToken': 'string'
}
```

I just want to list the stacks with below items. 
"Stack Name", "StackStatus" and "DriftInformation".  Please guide on this.

Thanks!

Update:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')

response = client.list_stacks(
    )

for stack in response['StackSummaries']:

    stack_summary = stack['StackName']

    print(stack_summary)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import boto3
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')

response = client.list_stacks()

for stack in response['StackSummaries']:

    stack_summary = stack['StackName']
    stack_status = stack['StackStatus']
    stack_drift_status = stack['DriftInformation']['StackDriftStatus']
    stack_drift_timestamp = stack['DriftInformation']['LastCheckTimestamp']
```

Comment: Thanks! Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ListCF.py", line 12, in <module>
    stack_drift_timestamp = stack['DriftInformation']['LastCheckTimestamp']
KeyError: 'LastCheckTimestamp'

Comment: You will need to debug the information that has come back to determine the cause. If you use `print(stack)` you will see the contents of the returned response and you can determine what course of action to take. It is possible that the `LastCheckTimestamp` simply isn't populated that the given stack. If you don't need that information, simply delete the line from the program.

Answer (score 1):

It should be the following:

```
list = response['StackSummaries'][0]['StackName']
```

`StackSummaries` is an array.

For full records, how to do it in the loop:

```
for stack in response['StackSummaries']:

    stack_summary = stack['StackName']
```

p.s.
Don't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: thanks but it prints only the name of the 1st Stack... My requirement is, it has to list all the stacks with just its name, status and driftinformation. Thanks

Comment: @user1562991 I added the loop to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I got the name. Please assist in adding two more values, "Status" and " Drift information'.

Comment: @user1562991 You have to process the stack_summaries in the loops body, not outsdie of it.

Comment: Yup that's it correct! I am able to get the Stack name. How do I get the 'Stack Status" and "Drift Information" please. Thanks

Comment: @user1562991 I'm sorry. You are deviating too much from the original issue you had posted in my view. You are free to make new question(s), specifically tailored for the new problems.

Comment: Sorry! But I have posted in the original question only to get these three details.  "Stack Name", " StackStatus" and "Drift Information". You could please check that and help! Thanks

Comment: @user1562991 `stack['StackStatus']`. For drift information need other query. @HuseyinGundogdu provided info about drift status.

Answer (score 0):

Returns the description for the specified stack; if no stack name was specified, then it returns the description(use "describe_stacks").

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')

response = client.describe_stacks(
  StackName='string',
  StackStatus= 'string',
  DriftInformation': {
            'StackDriftStatus': 'DRIFTED'|'IN_SYNC'|'UNKNOWN'|'NOT_CHECKED',
            'LastCheckTimestamp': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
        } 
)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ListCF1.py", line 8, in <module>
    'StackDriftStatus': 'DRIFTED'|'IN_SYNC'|'UNKNOWN'|'NOT_CHECKED',
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: I think this answer has confused output data with input parameters.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Desperately waiting for You!!! Please assist me on that. As per Marcin, I am able to get the Stack Name. Please assist in getting the Status and Drift information.